# Github: How to create a github repo in VS Code remotely without going to github

Tags: xcode, github, visual-studio-code

I am just curious.  In XCode I can create a github repo remotely without going to github.

How about doing the same thing in VS Code.  Usually we will go to github to create the repo first and use the command lines given to push to github.

Can this be all done remotely in VS Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode is probably just using the GitHub API.

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#create-an-organization-repository

You could do the same thing, but even simpler would be to use the `gh` command line tool.

https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install gh
gh auth login
gh repo create flatclass --public
```